# How many automated responses can I post through the YouTube API as the author to comments under my videos?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

While reviewing the YouTube API documentation, I couldn't find any policies regarding the number of automated responses to comments under my own videos. The API provides this functionality, which implies it's not entirely prohibited, but how many responses are considered safe?

I haven't tried anything yet as I wanted to get clarity on YouTube's policy before proceeding.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost#comments